# local economies vs local economy

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm talking about China's high-speed rail. I think "other cities" means that there is more than one local economy. Therefore, I need to use the plural "the local economies"? Or, I can use the singular "the local economy" even though there is more than one economy?

> Such fast, inexpensive travel can encourage people to visit other
> cities, injecting vast sums of money into the local
> **economies/economy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. Since there is more than one local economy being discussed you would use the plural "local economies".

Comment: +1 And to close the circle, to say "the local economy" would refer to the local economy surrounding the entire train infrastructure, like across the whole country, rather than the local area where there's a single train stop.